# Socket.io not emitting event to node server on react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I tried using socket.io client npm package on react native but no event is emitted when socket is initiated. i have tried everything possible but i still don't get a response on node server.
here is the socket.io setup:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:4000");
export default socket;
```

here is the code initiated when a screen loads:

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.emit('test', 'hello')
}, [])
```

here is the node server listener:

```
socket.on('test', (mssg) => { 
    console.log(mssg)
    // socket.emit('mssg', uuid.uuid())
})
```

Comment: Not enough information here to work with.  Have you implemented error handling on both the server and client sides to catch and log any potential errors during the connection or event emission process? That should give you enough information to resolve the issue.